# Combinin 2 array in 1 two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have 2 array like that `a[3] = "1","2","3"` and `b[3]="1","2","3"`.
Combine that 2 array in 1 2 dimensional array like `c[3][3]`

```
c[][]
"1" "1"
"2" "2"
"3" "3"
```

How i can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your two arrays have the same length, you could simply walk them both, and construct two-element arrays for your `c[][]`:

```
int commonLength = ... // This is the length shared by a and b
String[][] c = new String[commonLength][];
for (int i = 0 ; i != commonLength ; i++) {
    c[i] = new String[] { a[i], b[i] };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[][] combinedArray = new String[2][]; //since you have 2 arrays
combinedArray[0] = a;
combinedArray[1] = b;
```